# Fitted values from a statsmodel VECM dont satisfy the model exactly

Tags: statsmodels

I estimated a VECM and then wanted to sanity check the estimated model. I therefore expected that the fitted values would satisfy the model exactly. However, I find that it doesnt.

```
model = vecm.VECM(df.values, k_ar_diff = 3, coint_rank = 1, deterministic="nc")
modelres = model.fit()

n = modelres.nobs
l = modelres.k_ar

fv = modelres.fittedvalues.T # fitted values - neq x nobs

Phi = modelres.var_rep # VAR in levels
Ybar = np.column_stack([np.sum(np.column_stack([Phi[i,:,:] @ fv[:,j-i] for i in range(l)]),axis = 1) for j in range(l-1,nobs-1)])
```

Ybar above does not match fv which is what I would have expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's max abs of difference? Matching floating point numbers "exactly" is most of the time impossible.

Comment: Hi Josef. The difference is 97.56811 (ie not due to rounding). Thanks

Comment: (glad you found the answer.) As background here is a notebook that got left out in the VECM merge https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/2d97b1249ab40459fc0a703bc83da706

Answer (score 1):

After playing around the following works:

```
model = vecm.VECM(df.values, k_ar_diff = 3, coint_rank = 1, deterministic="nc")
modelres = model.fit()

n = modelres.nobs
l = modelres.k_ar

fv = modelres.y_all[:,l:]
Ybar = np.column_stack([np.sum(np.column_stack([Phi[i,:,:] @ fv[:,j-i] for i in range(l)]),axis = 1) for j in range(l-1,nobs-1)])

np.max(np.abs(modelres.fittedvalues.T[:,l:] - Ybar)) # check. will be close to 0!
```

Therefore the model.fittedvalues is being generated by running the model on the noisy data. Thanks